# Can't store byte array in google's datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore, uuid

I'm using Google's datastore in my Go app. I have a `Song` struct, which has a `uuid.UUID` field.

```
type Song struct {
    ID: uuid.UUID
    Title: string
    ...
}
```

This `UUID` is taken from [github.com/satori/go.uuid](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid/blob/master/uuid.go#L128) and is defined as

```
type UUID [16]byte
```

It seems that datastore can't handle byte arrays but in this use case only byte slices or strings. In the `json` package I can use a tag to interpret it as a string

```
type Song struct {
    ID: uuid.UUID `json:"id,string"`
    ....
}
```

Is there a way of telling datastore to interpret the `UUID` as a slice/string or do I either have to give up "type"-safety and just store a string or use a custom `PropertyLoadSaver`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Google's Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference):

> Valid value types are:
>
> - signed integers (int, int8, int16, int32 and int64),
> - bool,
> - string,
> - float32 and float64,
> - []byte (up to 1 megabyte in length),
> - any type whose underlying type is one of the above predeclared types,
> - ByteString,
> - *Key,
> - time.Time (stored with microsecond precision),
> - appengine.BlobKey,
> - appengine.GeoPoint,
> - structs whose fields are all valid value types,
> - slices of any of the above.

So, you will have to use a byte slice or string. You could do some behind the scenes manipulation when you need to do your setting or getting like ([Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/Ma72q5Ox0l)):

```
type uuid [16]byte

type song struct {
    u []byte
}

func main() {
    var b [16]byte
    copy(b[:], "0123456789012345")

    var u uuid = uuid(b) //this would represent when you get the uuid

    s := song{u: []byte(u[:])}

    copy(b[:], s.u)
    u = uuid(b)
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

This could also be done through methods. ([Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/lOdFTLRKOW))

Alternatively, you could have an entity specific to the datastore that carries the byte slice, and the transformers that go to and from that entity know how to do the conversion.